# xmpp Opera throws security error

Tags: security, xmpp, opera

gurus of programming!
I had created some chat, based on the book "XMPP programming", so I've included strophe.js and gab.js in my project. Everything is fine, service is working both in IE and Firefox. But not Opera, Opera in this case throws an exception

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security violation
Error thrown at line 2554, column 16 in <anonymous function: _processRequest>() in http://chat.aviportal.com/strophejs/strophe.js:
req.xhr.send(req.data);
called from line 2566, column 16 in <anonymous function: _processRequest>(i) in http://chat.aviportal.com/strophejs/strophe.js:
sendFunc();
called from line 2607, column 12 in <anonymous function: _throttledRequestHandler>() in http://chat.aviportal.com/strophejs/strophe.js:
this._processRequest(0);
called from line 2709, column 16 in <anonymous function: _onRequestStateChange>(func, req) in http://chat.aviportal.com/strophejs/strophe.js:
this._throttledRequestHandler();
```

Please let me know if anyone had similar problems, or maybe, I'll listen to your advices.
Thanks beforehands, Alex

Edited:
Ok, first of all, thanks for replying!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
        'http://chat.aviportal.com:5280/xmpp-httpbind');

    conn.connect('guest2@chat.aviportal.com', 'passwd', function (status) {
    if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        $(document).trigger('connected');
    } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
        $(document).trigger('disconnected');
    }
});
```

This is how I initialialize the strophe connection, the process bangs on conn.connect('guest2@chat.aviportal.com', etc)
The exception is thrown on that line.
BTW, what is CORS, Cross Domain Requests? The ejabberd on the same subdomain as the php file, so I don't think, but, there is a small possibility that it is ^_^

Comment: How do you load this library and what requests do you do with it?

Comment: Lack of CORS support in less than Opera 12?

Answer (score 1):

Despite your webserver running on the same domain as ejabberd, accessing a different port DOES  constitute a cross domain request and should raise a security exception. So, connecting to `domain:5280` is not the same as `domain:80`.

To solve this easily you should include a proxy on your setup. Most likely you already have apache or nginx in front, so you should just proxy `domain:80/http-bind` to go to `domain:5280`. For example for nginx you should have something like:

```
    location /http-bind {
        proxy_buffering off;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 55;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5280;
    }
```

in your nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ggozad, you know I've never considered that differnet port on the same domain considered to be crossdomain. Plugged the Nginx and everything is ok)))

Comment: @Cfyzz Glad it works, please accept the answer so that it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this without Jquery too !

Add following in the header of the file from where you are fetching the data:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this in your file if the libraries you are using are jQuery-based:

`jQuery.support.cors = true;`

This error is caused by Opera blocking a cross-site request. *CORS* will allow cross-site requests to be made from a normal web page if the server-side script allows it. Read more [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).

Currently, Opera only allows cross-site requests inside extensions as long as you [specify it](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-config-access/) in the **config.xml** file. Even so, however, if you try to use jQuery in an extension to make an XSS request, you will get a security violation unless you include in the file the line I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to do this in a such a way, and then will write if it's successfull.

Comment: I think Strophe.js does not use jQuery.